# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'

Tags: sass, npm, gulp

When I compile with `gulp`, I got an error like below. How can I fix it?

```
module.js:339
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/flyscoot.com/gulpfile.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Answer (score 100):

Just do `npm update` and then `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev` in your root folder, and then when you run you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: i did too, i don't know it's doesn't work cause i have issue permission

Comment: this worked for me as well! Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Edit your package.json. Change:

```
"gulp-sass": "^2.3.2"
```

to

```
"gulp-sass": "3.0.0"
```

Delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Source: https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/issues/4430#issuecomment-348927771

Comment: Yes it works. I updated with "gulp-sass": "3.1.0"

Answer (score 24):

Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406738/cant-get-gulp-to-run-cannot-find-module-gulp-util) question?

May be possible solution is:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Comment: i did it but file cannot delete

Comment: did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: use "rimraf" for deleting node_modules

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I resolve doing this `npm update`. But I receive the message about permission, so I run:

```
sudo chwon -R myuser /home/myUserFolder/.config
```

This set permissions for my user run npm comands like administrator. Then I run this again:

```
npm update
```

and this:

```
npm install gulp-sass
```

Then my problem with this was solved.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
npm install -g gulp-sass
```

or

```
npm install --save gulp-sass
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my new Windows 10 machine. I had to intall the Windows build tools with `npm install -g windows-build-tools`. (https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

i was also facing the same issue, 
The possible solution is to install the gulp-sass module, but if you will run the below command `npm install -g gulp-sass` or `npm install --save gulp-sass`, This is not going to be updated on node-sass project's end.

This version of node-sass is missing (returns a 404) and google web-starter-kit v0.6.5 has depended on it for a long time, since Dec 2016. So, it has been working for a long time and must have just disappeared.

Downloading binary from 
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download 
"https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

The only workaround is to upgrade node-sass:
`npm i gulp-sass@latest --save-dev` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had same error on Ubuntu 18.04

Delete your node_modules folder and run

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure python is installed on your machine, Python is required for node-sass.

Comment: If I am correct Python 2 is required/has some dependency for the gulp-saas@2.x.x version, gulp-saas@3.x.x or more will work fine without Python

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for days looking for answers. My error log was similar to this [npm just won't install node sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173180/npm-just-wont-install-node-sass)
The only problem was the node version. Maybe it can help some of you.

I downgraded my Node.js from 9.3.0 to 6.12.2 and run:

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 2):

In the root folder where `package.json` is located, run `npm outdated`. You'll get outdated packages returned with some details. In those details, you'll see the current version number of the outdated package.

After then, open the `package.json` file and manually change the version number of the corresponding package.

Then delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`. It should solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran : `npm i gulp-sass@latest --save-dev`

That did the magic for me

Answer (score 1):

Ive faced the same troubles with gulp-sass in my VSCode environment.
Also, I was observing a lot of fails during npm installing and I could not start gulp (as outcome).
The way how I fixed it:

- delete packages
- `npm i`
- `npm i gulp-sass --save-dev`

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [doc](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#migrating-to-version-5) to migrating to version 5.

```
npm install sass gulp-sass --save-dev
```

It's worked for me

```
node -v => v19.8.1
npm -v => 9.5.1
```

Comment: The npm command worked in Visual Studio Code for me without updating to version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are getting this error, please downgrade the **Node.js** you are using.

- **Step 1 :**

  Uninstall the one you are using and install the version you prefer. I installed **v6.12.3**. My previous Node.js version was **v9.4.0**.
- **Step 2 :**

  Download [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Yarn and I got the same issue and I solve it doing this:

```
delete node_modules
yarn install
yarn upgrade
 
yarn add gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix the error:

1. Delete `node_modules` directory.
2. Run `npm i gulp-sass@latest --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
2. `npm install gulp-sass sass`