# npm just won't install node sass

Tags: windows, powershell, npm, proxy, node-sass

I first encountered the issue when trying to use ionic and it needed the dependency for its templates. Then when I tried to install node-sass with npm myself the issue persisted. This is on `Windows 10 Version 1703`, both `nodejs 6.11.3` and `nodejs 8.4.0` tried out, ended up with same result. And VPN, http proxy were tried with no luck. Basically, it's saying :

> Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-57_binding.node"

when nothing is fiddled with ,it says :

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

when using npm set config proxy,it says something like:

> tunnel cannot be established

when using VPN,it waits forever at :

> node scripts/install.js

or outputs the same as if nothing is fiddled with.

When reporting an bug, you must provide this information:

- NPM version (npm -v): 5.3.0 with node latest(8.4.0), default version
  with node 6.11.3
- Node version (node -v):LTS(6.11.3) and LATEST(8.4.0)
- Node Process (node -p process.versions):

  { http_parser: '2.7.0', node: '8.4.0', v8: '6.0.286.52', uv:
  '1.13.1', zlib: '1.2.11', ares: '1.10.1-DEV', modules: '57', nghttp2:
  '1.22.0', openssl: '1.0.2l', icu: '59.1', unicode: '9.0', cldr:
  '31.0.1', tz: '2017b' }
- Node Platform (node -p process.platform): win32
- Node architecture (node -p process.arch): x64
- node-sass version (node -p "require('node-sass').info"): Error:
  Cannot find module 'node-sass'
- npm node-sass versions (npm ls node-sass): `-- (empty)

and there is the output

```
---> npm install -g node-sass
C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass -> C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass

> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.4.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE
gyp verb check python version `C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "3.6.2\r\n"
gyp verb could not find "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-10T18_52_13_062Z-debug.log
```

Then someone tells me:

> Well `ECONNREFUSED` is easy - you have configured npm to talk to the
>   proxy at 127.0.0.1 (localhost) port 443 but the proxy does not seem to
>   be active for this port. Please check proxy/VPN software configuration
>   - port numbers must match.

But the thing is I don't have proxy configured. I tried `npm config rm proxy`,and `npm config delete proxy`, I even tried just go with it and set up a proxy then point npm to that proxy like I described above, nothing works.And here is the powershell enviroment config just in case:

```
⚡ rick@DESKTOP-1NVA03E  ~  $reg = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"

⚡ rick@DESKTOP-1NVA03E  ~  $settings = Get-ItemProperty -Path $reg                                                    

⚡ rick@DESKTOP-1NVA03E  ~  $settings.ProxyServer
127.0.0.1:1080 

⚡ rick@DESKTOP-1NVA03E  ~  $settings.ProxyEnable
0
```

Comment: For those who have similar issues, try my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314607/error-cannot-find-module-gulp-sass/47982544#47982544

Answer (score 4):

I just came across the same problem. It was solved by installing Python v2.7 in C:\Python27\ . (I previously only had Python 3.6 installed in C:\Program Files\Python36\ )

Comment: I resolved the issue by using taobao's mirror of npm repository. I'm in China.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like compatibility issue of the node-sass module. You can solve this issue by following a few steps.

give the below command in your terminal

```
node list node-sass
```

It will list all your node-sass dependencies( including nested dependencies)

check all versions of node sass and also check supported [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) for Node.js installed in your machine

You can either change the Node.js version in your machine or add the following code in package.json

```
    "resolutions": {
        "*/node-sass": "*"
     },
```

Remove node_module folder and yarn.lock file (assuming that you use yarn) once you make the above change.

Install the node_modules using `yarn install`

If you prefer npm instead of yarn you might need to install an additional package called [npm force resolutions](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for days looking for possible answers. I downgraded my node.js from 9.3.0 to v6.12.2 and run (all errors were gone):

```
        npm update
```

Hopefully, this can help some of you who have encountered similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by changing compatible version of node.

It may be problem of compatibility of node version with node-sass version you are using.
Please check the below document to see the compatibility table and install appropriate node version.