# Ionic - Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, sass, gulp

I have a Ionic v1 app and when I try to run the app via a gulp command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass' from '/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code'
at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:40:15)
at requireFn (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:74:25)
at Object.get [as sass] (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:117:41)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/tasks/config/compile.js:30:18)
at module.exports (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
at /Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/gulp-sequence/index.js:68:12
at apply (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/thunks/index.js:355:38)
```

So I followed the instructions mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314607/error-cannot-find-module-gulp-sass) and tried `npm update`
But then I get the following errors:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN tuintalent@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN tuintalent@1.1.1 No license field.
npm WARN The package gulp-concat is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My environment for this app is:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
Node       : v8.9.4
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Removing the `node_modules` and doing a `npm install` also gives other errors.

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bertcarremans/Tuintalent/code/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN tuintalent@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN tuintalent@1.1.1 No license field.
npm WARN The package gulp-concat is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather late for OP - however, a node-gyp make error means "node is compiling a module's native code of c/c++ and failed" - in a similar case I encountered recently, MacOS build tools wasn't valid, can be caused when XCODE gets updated but Command Line Tools (c++ compiler etc) isn't ready for use yet.

For typical solutions to node-gyp issues on MacOS, the module has decent documentation - [MacOS node-gyp fixes](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md)

Answer (score -1):

Just do `npm update` and then `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev` in your root folder, and then when you run you shouldn't have any issues.

or do

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Comment: npm update did not work as I mentioned above. Removing the node_modules and doing npm install results in other errors. I've edited my question to display these errors.

Comment: Hi @BertCarremans what did you end up doing to resolve this issue?