# How can I resolve issue with "Cannot find module 'gulp-util'"?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've spent an hour this morning already looking at the existing SO answers as well as elsewhere on the internet.

When I run `gulp`, I get the following error

```
➜  qwer git:(master) ✗ gulp
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

I have followed the suggestions to clear out `node_modules` and `npm install` again; no dice.

I have installed an older version of node/npm and tried, making sure to remove global installs of gulp.  Still no luck.  (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

```
npm rm --global gulp
```

I can run gulp on a remote environment and it works just fine, so it appears to be a local configuration issue.

```
➜  qwer git:(master) ✗ node -v
v5.10.1
➜  qwer git:(master) ✗ npm -v
3.8.3
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "qwer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "asdlf kjalsdk fjalsdk jfla",
  "main": "config/gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "jstify": "^0.14.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "yargs": "^4.6.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.12.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@crystal.github.com:crystalcommerce/pos-frontend.git"
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

Steps to reproduce error

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
gulp
```

Comment: Same question, but complementary answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406738/cant-get-gulp-to-run-cannot-find-module-gulp-util

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears I had an old version of gulp that wasn't getting removed when I called `npm rm --global gulp`.

```
which gulp
➜ /usr/local/bin/gulp

# remove old version; not sure where this came from; perhaps brew?
rm /usr/local/bin/gulp

which gulp
➜ /Users/davidvezzani/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/gulp

# for good measure
rm /Users/davidvezzani/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/gulp

npm install --global gulp-cli

which gulp
➜ /Users/davidvezzani/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/gulp

gulp

[07:15:22] Using gulpfile ~/reliacode/crystal_commerce/qwer/gulpfile.js
[07:15:22] Starting 'default'...
[07:15:22] Finished 'default' after 71 μs
```

Comment: _"remove old version; not sure where this came from; perhaps brew?"_ -- that's where NPM installs gulp for me on OS X, when I install it globally.  Just FYI

Comment: apt maybe, sudo apt install gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [npm-shrink-wrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to force lock npm package json to use the specific gulp version irrespective of whatever is there in the npm global cache,or you can try cleaning the npm cache folder using [npm clean cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache).