# Cannot find module 'gulp-util'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, vuejs2, laravel-elixir

I have some trouble with gulp. I use laravel/elixir which has gulp as its dependency. I did the steps like here [Can't get Gulp to run: cannot find module 'gulp-util'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406738/cant-get-gulp-to-run-cannot-find-module-gulp-util) but still no success. Actually the `gulp-util` files are inside the node_modules folder...
[image]

[image]

Anyway I'm using Xubuntu 17.04 64bit if it counts.

Comment: Have you tried updating nodejs and npm, then dumping the `node_modules` directory, and reinstalling with `npm install`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Gulp to run: cannot find module 'gulp-util'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406738/cant-get-gulp-to-run-cannot-find-module-gulp-util)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and tried almost everything.
But then I realized that the error does not point to the local gulp in the respective project but to the global one (/usr/lib/nodejs/gulp/...).

What solved the problem for me was to update that respective gulp:

```
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

I am not sure if it is in general correct that the global gulp is used or if the one of the project should be used instead. But at least for now I was able to solve the problem with that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK I will try it.

Comment: This finally solved my problem on Ubuntu 17.10 with node 8.4.3
Think it worth to say that I have gulp installed from apt-get.
Thank you